# Error importing routes configuration file

Tags: coldfusion, mapping, coldbox

I'm updating from Coldbox 3.8.1 to coldbox 4.1.0 and the error I keep getting is:

> Error importing routes configuration file: Could not find the
>   included template config/Routes.cfm. Note: If you wish to use an
>   absolute template path (for example, template="/mypath/index.cfm")
>   with include, you must create a mapping for the path using the
>   ColdFusion Administrator. Or, you can use per-application settings to
>   specify mappings specific to this application by specifying a mappings
>   struct to THIS.mappings in Application.cfc. 
>  Using relative paths
>   (for example, template="index.cfm" or template="../index.cfm") does
>   not require the creation of any special mappings. It is therefore
>   recommended that you use relative paths with include whenever
>   possible.

Here's the thing though, in order for it to throw that error it checks to make sure the file exists with a `fileExists(expandPath(config/Routes.cfm))` as well as I have manually checked and saw the file does in fact exist. I've tried changing the location for where it's looking and also using an absolute path adding the mapping to CF but it keeps popping up with this error. Any ideas on why if the file does exist, and CF can see it why it says it can't?

Comment: Probably a permission issue?